# login.microsoftonline.com doesn't redirect to the specified Redirect URL

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, msal.js, adal.js

We are having problem with ADAL redirect authentication in MS Team Desktop client recently.

We have a custom Teams app package (Team Tab) to display a page on our application server. The page uses ADAL JS library to get Graph token to access One Drive. Since the page is displayed in iframe and will be used in Teams desktop client, we use page redirect authentication in ADAL. From debug console, we can see the issue happened when ADAL sent request to “login.microsoftonline.com”(login_hint  parameter is used to specify current user account). The flow stopped with error saying the “login.microsoftonline.com” can’t be displayed in iframe. In the past, “login.microsoftonline.com” simply redirected the browser to the specified redirect URL and auth flow completed without any problem.

Our application server has implemented SSO with Azure. Implicit auth flow is used to get the token. The issue only happens in Teams desktop client, we use ADAL popup (not supported in desktop client) to get token in browser. The flow was working before April. Seems to me that something has changed recently at the Microsoft login page.

Just wondering if anybody has the same issue. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using Teams SSO, which uses MSAL, instead of ADAL? See here for a sample: https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/master/samples/tab-sso

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware of the SSO sample, but it uses a different auth flow and will take some effort to re-implement our app. Just wondering if there is quick fix can make the existing app work. And it was working fine for a couple of years.

Comment: I agree with @Hilton's recommendation above. You should consider moving away from ADAL to MSAL, as the prior is getting deprecated. Also have a look at [ADAL to MSAL migration document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-compare-msal-js-and-adal-js) too.